# background process not ending in bash 

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, background-process

When I execute another script from my main script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
if cond1; then
    stuff
    sleep 10
    ./script1.sh &
elif cond2; then
    more stuff
    ./script2.sh &
else
    echo "foo"
fi 
stuff 
echo "Hello World"
```

script1.sh & script2.sh do no seem to exit until I close the main script even though I have issued the ***exit*** command inside the script1 & script2. Am I missing something? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should better format your code, this looks horrible!

Comment: Are script1 & 2 reaching the exit command?

Comment: I appologise for the poor layout of the code, it is just meant as a quick example. They execute all commands upto the exit statement, I don't understand why they shouldn't exit.

Comment: @hochl: You can do it! (You could have done it).

Comment: @bikerben: Don't apologize for mistakes - correct them. Better, of course, avoid them, but we can't avoid all mistakes, but we can edit our old posts.

Comment: it would really help to see the output you get. Do you ever see 'Hello World'? Do you expect to see it? (I would). Do you see anything like 'jobs' appearing? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example should work just fine. I suspect there is something wrong with `script1.sh` or `script2.sh`. Or could it be that you are misinterpreting the shell’s notification of finished jobs?